shadcn storing state in searchParam queries and nextjs 14
i have a shadcn form component that has Dialog, inside is is a form with Select,input, textArea, updloadPicture ( with uploadthing) and Switch. in another component i set  a query to call a my api using it.
for some reson when i change my query which is only connected to the one i defined.
it takes the input and description elements from shadcn form and places them in a query. they serve no purpose what so ever but im just interested in how it could be happening.
ps  : i still get state from react-hook-forms
"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";

import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectLabel,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";

import { z } from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Textarea } from "@/components/ui/textarea";
import { FileUploader } from "@/components/shared/FileUploader";
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useUploadThing } from "@/utils/uploadthing";


const formSchema = z.object({
  itemName: z.string().min(2).max(50),
  menuGroup: z.string().min(2).max(50, { message: "select a group" }),
  itemDescription: z
    .string()
    .min(2, { message: "description must be between 2 and 50 characters" })
    .max(50, { message: "description must be between 2 and 50 characters" }),
  itemPicUrl: z
    .string()
    .url({ message: "Invalid URL format" })
    .min(1, { message: "Image For picture URL is required" })
    .default(""),
  // .optional(),
  itemPrice: z.string().refine((value) => /^\d+$/.test(value), {
    message: "Must contain only numerical digits.",
  }),
  isMenuItemPublic: z.boolean().default(true),
});

export function AddItem({ menuId }: { menuId: string }) {
  const [itemPicUrl, setItemPicUrl] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const { startUpload } = useUploadThing("imageUploader");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      menuGroup: "",
      itemName: "",
      itemDescription: "",
      itemPicUrl: "https://tippernetwork.com",
      itemPrice: "",
      isMenuItemPublic: true,
    },
  });

  // 2. Define a submit handler.
  async function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    event?.preventDefault();
    console.log("menuId", menuId);
    if (values) {
      setOpen(false);
      form.reset();
    }
    let uploadItemPicUrl = values.itemPicUrl;
    console.log("values", values);
    // if (itemPicUrl.length > 0) {
    //   const uploadedImageUrl = await startUpload(itemPicUrl);
    //   if (!uploadedImageUrl) {
    //     return;
    //   }
    //   uploadItemPicUrl = uploadedImageUrl[0].url;
    // }
    console.log(values);
  }

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <DialogTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="outline">Add Item</Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Add Item</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Make changes to your Menu here. Click save when you're done.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <div>
          <Form {...form}>
            <form
              id="formId"
              className="space-y-8"
              onSubmit={(event) => {
                // event.preventDefault();
                form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
              }}
            >
              <div>
                <div>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="menuGroup"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        <FormControl>
                          <Select onValueChange={field.onChange} defaultValue={field.value}>
                          <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px]">
                              <SelectValue placeholder="Select a fruit" />
                            </SelectTrigger>
                            <SelectContent>
                              <SelectGroup>
                                <SelectLabel>Fruits</SelectLabel>
                                <SelectItem value="apple">Apple</SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="banana">Banana</SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="blueberry">
                                  Blueberry
                                </SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="grapes">Grapes</SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="pineapple">
                                  Pineapple
                                </SelectItem>
                              </SelectGroup>
                            </SelectContent>
                          </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          Write the name of your menu item{" "}
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="itemName"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        {/* <FormLabel>Item Name</FormLabel> */}
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input placeholder="Item name" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          Write the name of your menu item{" "}
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="itemDescription"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        {/* <FormLabel>Item Description</FormLabel> */}
                        <FormControl>
                          <Textarea placeholder="Item Description" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          describe your menu item{" "}
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="itemPicUrl"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        {/* <FormLabel>Item Picture</FormLabel> */}
                        <FormControl>
                          <FileUploader
                            onFieldChange={field.onChange}
                            imageUrl={field.value}
                            setFiles={setItemPicUrl}
                            label="the cover image of the item"
                          />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          this is your item's pic{" "}
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="flex">
                  <FormField
                    control={form.control}
                    name="itemPrice"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        {/* <FormLabel>Item Price</FormLabel> */}
                        <FormControl>
                          <Input placeholder="price" type="number" {...field} />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          This is your items price.
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />

                  <FormField
                    // control={form.control}
                    name="isMenuItemPublic"
                    render={({ field }) => (
                      //
                      <FormItem>
                        {/* <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel> */}
                        <FormControl>
                          {/* <Switch
                            defaultChecked={isPublic}
                            onCheckedChange={handleToggleButton}
                            checked={isPublic}
                          />{" "} */}
                          <Switch
                            checked={field.value}
                            onCheckedChange={field.onChange}
                          />
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormDescription>
                          is Item Public.
                        </FormDescription>
                        <FormMessage />
                      </FormItem>
                    )}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <DialogFooter>
                <Button
                  form="formId"
                  // onClick={() => {
                  //   form.trigger();
                  //   if (form.formState.isValid) {
                  //     onSubmit(form.getValues());
                  //   }
                  // }}
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Save changes
                </Button>
              </DialogFooter>
            </form>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

my group component for queries
"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { formUrlQuery, removeKeysFromQuery } from "@/lib/utils";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MenuGroups = ({ groups }: { groups: string[] }) => {
  const [group, setGroup] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  console.log('searchParams', searchParams)

  useEffect(() => {
    let newUrl = "";

    if (group) {
      newUrl = formUrlQuery({
        params: searchParams.toString(),
        key: "group",
        value: group,
      });
    } else {
      newUrl = removeKeysFromQuery({
        params: searchParams.toString(),
        keysToRemove: ["group"],
      });
    }

    router.push(newUrl, { scroll: false });
  }, [group, searchParams]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {groups.map((group, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {" "}
            <Button
              name={group}
              onClick={() => setGroup(group)}
              className="rounded-md bg-primary px-2 py-1 text-white hover:cursor-pointer hover:text-black"
            >
              {group}
            </Button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuGroups;

